# Using MSOL for solving BIDS problem

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, lo.logic, descriptive-complexity

From ["Linear Time Solvable Optimization Problems on Graphs of Bounded Clique Width" (B. Courcelle et al)](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/eric.thierry/Graphes2007/cmr00.pdf)  we know that any problem that can be written on MSOL (Monadic Second Order Logic) has a linear algorithm that solves it on graphs with bounded [clique-width](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique-width). However the algorithm takes as input the K-expression of the graph and obtaining it is NP-Complete if K is not fixed.

In a later paper ["Improved bottleneck domination algorithms" (T. Kloks et al)](http://lita.sciences.univ-metz.fr/~kratsch/publications/bottleneck.ps), there is a description of several bottleneck problems, including the Bottleneck Independent Dominating Set (BIDS) which asks for an **independent dominating set** *D* such that maximum weight over the vertices in *D* is as small as possible.

In section 4.4 they give an algorithm with complexity $O(5^kk^3n)$ for the BIDS problem on graphs with clique-width bounded and where the k-expression is given.
As far as I know this problem can be written in MSOL and hence the first paper (which is earlier) gives a better result for the same problem.

Am I wrong? Is there any technical detail or concept that I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The $O(5^kk^3n)$ is linear in $n$ as well and $O(n)$ for bounded $k$.
The Courcelle, Makowski, Rotics paper does not give explicit/good upper bounds for the contants hidden in the big-O.  If you want to make the dependency on $k$ explicit as in $O(f(k)n)$, then additional work is required.

See "[Faster Algorithms on Clique and Branch Decompositions](http://www.springerlink.com/index/10.1007/978-3-642-15155-2_17)" by
Bodlaender et al (MFCS 2010)  for recent algorithms for domination-style algorithms.

Comment: Moreover, the constants in the generic algorithm for MSOL are galactic (see http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2010/10/23/galactic-algorithms/ ).  Each quantifier alternation in the MSO formula causes an exponential increase, so straighforward translations typically have at least a $2^{2^k}$ factor.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon Aksing out of curiosity, are there (special) cases when the the algorithm obtained by converting from MSOL give linear time non-galactic algorithms?

Comment: @AndrásSalamon Could you please point to a reference (eg, relevant section in "Graph Structure and Monadic Second-Order Logic")that assert that the constants in the generic algorithm for MSOL are galactic. (There are a mention of huge constants in section 6.3 of the mentioned book; but is there anything that precisely says each quantification causes exponential increase; sorry i am a newbie)

Comment: The comment about exponential increase is a heuristic; proving such lower bounds would be a breakthrough.

Comment: @CyriacAntony "The complexity of first-order and monadic second-order logic revisited" by Frick and Grohe is a good starting point, it shown non-elementary lower bounds. Also there is a German dissertation thesis by Weyer ("Modifizierte parametrische Komplexitätstheorie" / Univ. Freiburg 2007) that explicitly shows an exponential increase per quantifier alternation (chapter 6.4) assuming $P != NP$. It's a bit hard to read due to the notation for the complexity classed used, though. And it's in German.

Comment: I stumbled upon a survey that give references on lower bound along with other useful information: *Practical algorithms for MSO model-checking on tree-decomposable graphs* [https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265788909_Practical_algorithms_for_MSO_model-checking_on_tree-decomposable_graphs] , Langer et. al.